# selenium with firefox close tab by javascript but SetTimeout() not ok

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I use multithreaded way to open tab and when page finish load close tab

this is my open tab code

```java
((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript("window.open('"+url+"')");
```

When close tab,i iterate `webDriver.getWindowHandles()` and use function `executeScript`,but find some error,this is my code

this code work ok in chrome,it close all tab,but in firefox some windowHandler are closed and some not

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("setTimeout(function(){window.close()},10000)");
```

or

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("setInterval(function(){window.close()},10000)");
```

I try to use this code, but it's also like above code

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("var script = document.createElement('script');\n" +
      "script.type = 'text/javascript';\n" +
      "script.innerHTML =  'setTimeout(function(){window.close()},10000);';\n" +
      "script.innerHTML =  'window.close()';\n" +
      "document.body.appendChild(script);");
```

but when i delete `"script.innerHTML =  'setTimeout(function(){window.close()},10000);';\n" +` only use `window.close()` it work close all tab, but does not meet the needs

so i think maybe `setTimeout` and `setInterval` function cause this problem in firefox

then i change code to this

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("var start = null;\n" +
     "\n" +
     "function step(timestamp) {\n" +
     "  if (!start) start = timestamp;\n" +
     "  var progress = timestamp - start;\n" +
     "  if (progress < 2000) {\n" +
     "    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);\n" +
     "  } else {\n" +
     "    window.close();\n" +
     "  }\n" +
     "}\n" +
     "\n" +
     "window.requestAnimationFrame(step);");
```

it's also some windowHandler are closed and some not

i don't know how can i close tab in firefox by javascript

The requirement is to close the tab directly after 10 seconds, or close the tab after the page is loaded

Comment: @ScamCast i try `"script.text = setTimeout(function(){window.close()},10000);\n"+` it's also not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but it seems you are trying to open a new tab, run some code, then close 10 seconds after it was opened?

I've tested this in firefox and it works with multiple tabs and each one closes on it's own.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
    "function openAndClose(url, timeout){" +
    "    var tab = window.open(url);" +
    "    setTimeout(function(){tab.close()},timeout);" +
    "}" +
    "openAndClose('https://www.google.com', 3000);");
```

If this is not it, could you explain your problem a little more clearly.

Comment: thx, i use a stupid method to close tab by new thread scan all windowHandler after other thread open tab, when use your code `executeScript` include open and close tab code, it work well.